# Difference between the meaning of "noun which verb" and "noun verb ing"

Tags: grammar, gerunds

For example:
What is the difference between the meaning of "Health centers **which conduct** free medical check-ups..." and "Health centers **conducting** free medical check-ups..."?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] *Health centers [which conduct free medical check-ups]*.
>
> [2] *Health centers [conducting free medical check-ups]*.

The difference is mainly a syntactic one.

Gerund-participial and past participial clauses as modifiers in NP structure are semantically similar to relative clauses. Leaving aside the progressive aspectuality in [2], the two constructions have similar meanings, though the subordinate modifying clauses are different.

In [1] the bracketed constituent belongs to the class of integrated relative clauses while that in [2] is a non-finite clause -- more specifically a gerund-participial clause.

Comment: The difference in meaning is?

Comment: He said they are similar in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences have the same meaning, but they differ structurally. 
The first one is a complex sentence with a relative clause /starting with 'which'/. The second one is a simple sentence with an attribute /expressed by a participal construction/.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with that. "Conducting free medical check-ups" is a subordinate non-finite clause and hence the second example is also a complex one.

Comment: I agree,  there are two approaches to   the  status of the clause. I follow the  one, according to which the clause consists of the subject and the predicate /finite verb/.
The second one is accepted in the sense of the so called 'secondary predication'.